# ASP.Net Export Data to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Wondering what is a good library I can use with VS2005 to export data to a excel file.  The file has some formatting like background colors and colspans.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that uses a trick to output HTML to an Excel file. I have found that you can trick excel into opening an HTML by setting the content type of the output to "application/excel".

In the code below secresults is an HTML div like so:

```
<div id="secresults" runat="server" visible="false" class="secresults">
Content or data here.
</div>
```

In code behind:

```
Response.ClearContent();
string filename = "Output" + istartDate.ToShortDateString() + ".xls";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

secresults.RenderControl(htw);


Response.Write(sw.toString());
Response.End();
```

I have found that you can use some html formatting in excel. To test which formatting you can use you can create an html file and rename it to a .xls file, then open it with excel. You can get a pretty good idea about what HTML Excel will read.

Comment: Nice.  Did not know you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking the class from the following website, and adapting it to your needs.

[Mikes Knowledge Base - ExportToExcel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

By default, this class takes a DataSet, DataTable or List<>, and exports it into a **genuine** Excel 2007 .xlsx file, using the *OpenXML* libraries (also provided).

It doesn't currently attempt to add any formating to the Excel cells (DataTables only store values, not formating, colors, horizontal alignment, etc !) but it should be a good place to start from.

All source code is provided, free of charge, so you can adapt it as required.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library in the past, but I normally just spit out a CSV file.

[C# class library for exporting data to CSV/Excel file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExportClassLibrary.aspx)

Comment: I saw that library also. Can you do formatting with that library? Meaning create background colors, change the font of the text for some columns etc.

Comment: Not sure, I doubt it, sounds like you might need a reporting solution like SQL Reporting Services, Active Reports...etc

Answer (score 1):

If you have predefined layout of the document, [Templater](http://templater.info/) will probably fit your description.

Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/Templater/Examples/tree/master/FoodOrder) on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this [codeplex project (Excel Package)](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/). One technique is to start with a formatted template, then modify the template. That is much easier than applying a lot of styling commands starting with an empty spreadsheet.